# php, DELETE doesn't work

Tags: php, android, mysql

android java file.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", username));
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("channel", channel));
// getting details by making HTTP request
 JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
"localhost/users/url_delete_users.php", "POST", params);
```

---

**url_delete_users.php**

```
 if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['channel'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];     $channel = $_POST['channel'];
     // include db connect class
     require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
     // connecting to db
     $db = new DB_CONNECT();
     // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = $name AND channel=$channel");**
```

is there something wrong at mysql_query?
it doesn't work...
(create db php source works well. only delete gets error)

Comment: Maybe '' (quotes) are missing in your sql query around $name and $channel

Comment: `only delete gets error)` Well.. what is the error ?

Comment: Try to debug with mysql_query(....) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure if everything is ok above then try this :

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = '".$name."' AND channel='".$channel."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
  $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE 
              `name` = '".$name."' AND channel='".$channel."' ") 
              or die(mysql_error());
```

instead of

```
 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = $name AND channel=$channel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = '$name' AND channel='$channel'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

`$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = $name AND channel=$channel");`

should be

`$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name = '$name' AND channel='$channel'");`